# Laravel package parameter not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a package in `Laravel 5.4` where i do routing. It looks like this in my 
serviceprovider:

```
 public function boot()
    {
        $routeConfig = [
            'namespace'  => 'LarsJanssen\GetJson\Controllers',
            'prefix'     => 'api',
            'middleware' => [
                'api',
            ],
        ];
        $this->getRouter()->group($routeConfig, function ($router) {
            $router->get('/feeddex/{store}', [
                'uses' => 'GetJsonController@store',
                'as'   => 'getjsonproperly.store',
            ]);
        });
    }
```

The problem is that the parameter store never works!

The controller method looks like this:

```
 public function store($store)
 {
     //my code
 }
```

Error message:

```
Missing argument 1
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there any other route that uses `GetJsonController@store` ??

Comment: Nope this is so weird :(

Comment: Ok try it with this `public function store($store = null)`

Comment: Yes then its working but it's always null. Even when I pass a parameter.

Comment: Check itwithout group just for testing `$this->getRouter()->get('/feeddex/{store}', [....`

Comment: Thanks already working. Had a middleware that did weird thinks.